# translate script with sed commands cuda installation

Tags: sed

could anyone tell me what these sed commands do and how I can do/insert them by hand.

```
sed -i  '/^__func__.*__syncthreads/ {
i\
#if !defined(__CUDA__)
N
N
N
N
a\
#endif
}' $device_functions.h

sed -i  '/^#define __device__ / {
i\
#if !defined(__CUDA__)
N
N
N
N
N
N
N
N
N
N
N
a\
#endif
}' $host_defines.h
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what the programs do:

- The first program searches for lines that match `^__func__.*__syncthreads` and wraps that line and the next four following lines (the four `N`) in `#if !defined(__CUDA__)` and `#endif` by using `i\` (immediate output) and `a\` (appended output).
- The second program searches for lines that match `^#define __device__`  and wraps that line and the next eleven following lines in `#if !defined(__CUDA__)` and `#endif`.

This is done on the file specified by `$host_defines.h` and `$device_functions.h`, respectively, in an in-place manner (`-i`), so the files’ contents are changed.